# Incomplete type when dereferencing pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a header file which gives the definition

```
typedef struct dyn_array dyn_array_t
```

I have a .c file which implements it

```
struct dyn_array {
    size_t size;
    void* array;
};
```

In a different .c file I pass a pointer of this type to a function.

```
bool first_come_first_serve(dyn_array_t* ready_queue){
    size_t limit = ready_queue->size; 
    //...
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other .c file does not see the `struct dyn_array` definition.  It has no understanding of the members like `size`.

---

If more than 1 .c file needs to understand the structure, move the below to the .h file

```
struct dyn_array {
  size_t size;
  void* array;
};
```

The alternative is to create a function that gets the member and keep the definition of `dyn_array_t` local  in `dyn_array.c`.  This is [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) - a good design goal.

```
// in dyn_array.h
typedef struct dyn_array dyn_array_t;
size_t get_size(const dyn_array_t* ready_queue);

// in different.c
#include <dyn_array.h>
bool first_come_first_serve(dyn_array_t* ready_queue){
  size_t limit = get_size(ready_queue); 
  //...
}

// in dyn_array.c
#include <dyn_array.h>

struct dyn_array {
    size_t size;
    void* array;
};

size_t get_size(const dyn_array_t* ready_queue) {
   return ready_queue->size; 
}
```

Comment: And be sure to #include the .h file in whatever .c files need the struct's definition.

Comment: I'm including the .h file in both so I'm thinking it's a problem with my makefile

Comment: @OmegaCollision It is not only if the .h file is included.  It is a question of what is in the .h file.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think to write a getter function. That was what I was trying to go for thank you

Answer (score 1):

"Incomplete Type" means you have only declared / used the type, and not explained it. Your second `.c` file might `#include "a.h"` but note that the **definition** of `dyn_array` is in `a.c` and not `a.h`

To fix this, both declare and define `dyn_array` in `a.h`:

```
struct dyn_array {
    size_t size;
    void* array;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to complete the type definition to be able to dereference a pointer to it and access its fields.  You have to put the type definition in a header (possibly different than the one you used to put the `typedef` declaration) and include it in the second file also, to be able to access past the pointer.  The compiler allows you to access a pointer to incomplete type definition, as long as you don't need the details of that type.  As in your second file, the compiler knows nothing about how the structure is built, so it cannot access the `size` field.

If you need some parts of your code not to be able to access the internal details of your data type, and others be completely aware of it, then prepare two header files (one public and other private) like this:

## dynarry.h

```
typedef struct dyn_array dyn_array_t;
size_t get_size(const dyn_array_t* ready_queue);
```

## dynarryP.h

```
#include "dynarry.h"
struct dyn_array {
    size_t size;
    void *array;
};
```

and then, in the modules using as clients the library include only the `"dynarry.h"`, while in the internal implementation you `#include "dynarryP.h"`.  This is somewhat similar to object oriented programming, in relation to *hidding internal implementation details*.